# Moving JTextArea Scroll to Caret

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jtextarea

How can I move the current scroll view of a JTextArea down so that the caret appears at the top of the JTextArea? Thanks.

Comment: Nope, I mean down as in pressing the down arrow on the scroll. But I guess the view moves up if you look at it that way.

Comment: Because usually when you scroll down through setting the caret position, the caret will appear at the bottom of the JTextArea, I want the scroll to keep moving past this so that it appears at the top.

Comment: My mistake you're right. I do mean up. Move the scroll view of the area up. But the actual action would be scrolling down.

Comment: do you just need a jscrollpane?

Comment: *"I want the scroll to keep moving past this so that it appears at the top."*  That would ***not*** be 'the path of least surprise' for an end user!  I for one would be quite irritated if I held down the right arrow key to get to the end of the text, only to see the caret jump to the top of the text area.

Comment: It's a box that I am adding search results to. Each batch of results that the user could add I want the caret to be at the top along with the scroll view. @Jake223 I already have a scrollpane.

Comment: @AndrewThompson That isn't what I meant. When text is added to this box I want the view to have the start of the most recently added text at the top of the textarea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
Point pt = textArea.getCaret().getMagicCaretPosition();
Rectangle rect = new Rect(pt, new Dimension(1, 10));
textArea.scrollRectToVisible(rect);
```

One can also use the `getDocument` for a better selection.

Answer (score -1):

Place the JTextArea inside a JScrollPane, and invoke

```
scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(value);
```